# Where do the packages from software updates get saved?

Tags: updates

Where do the updates provided by Ubuntu gets stored on the hard-disk. I see that the updates are downloaded and then installed.

It would of great help if i can get the location of the downloaded updates so that I can save the downloads to a usb or an external hard-drive because in case i need to format my system i don't need to download the updates again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the individual updates in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

When new packages are published they are added to the pool, they don't replace the older updates, so over time you'll need to prune them, or use a dedicated tool like mentioned here:

- [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

To save your updates (and all downloaded packages) you can use the `aptoncd` program.